# Emacs: Rinari. How to make haml files also open in rinari-minor-mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, haml, rinari

When using rinari, rinari-minor-mode is enabled when editing any .rb file. Though, when opening .haml files rinari-minor-mode is disabled.

How do I make emacs also automatically enable rinari-minor-mode when editing .haml files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
(add-hook 'haml-mode-hook 'rinari-minor-mode)
```